# Schengen visa Travel

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I live in South Africa and would like to visit France and Italy. I was hoping to enter in Paris and fly back home from Rome. It it possible to exit the Europe from a different country of entry?

Comment: Yes.  I have to add some more characters to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter and leave from any Schengen country :)